# Stumped: cannot get results to show with jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I threw up a simple example with jquery autocomplete and cannot get it to work. I have no idea what's wrong, no errors and nothing's wrong with my JSON, yet it doesn't display results.

Here's my code

```
<div class="demo">

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="title">Title: </label>
    <input id="test" />
</div>


<script>
$(function() {
        $( "#test" ).autocomplete({
            source: "/searchbackend.php"
        });
});
</script>
```

JSON:

```
{"title":["Metroid: Other M"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your output should be like this `["HELLO","HOW","DO","YOU","DO","?"]` so use 1d array to output json.

```
$array = array("HELLO", "HOW", "DO", "YOU", "DO", "?");

echo json_encode($array);
```

Man .. this perfectly works.

```
$array = array(
                array("label" => "HELLO", "value" => "H"), 
                array("label" => "HOW", "value" => "H"), 
                array("label" => "DO", "value" => "D"),
                array("label" => "YOU", "value" => "Y"),
                array("label" => "DO", "value" => "D"));

echo json_encode($array);
```

Also try changing `source: "/searchbackend.php"` to `source: "searchbackend.php"`

Comment: Thanks, this was part of the problem... now it seems that the autocomplete won't work unless I have "value" and "label" in my json array. So I can't use just "title"

Trying to find out if there's a way to specify custom params rather than hard editing the js source.

Comment: @x3sphere .. mean you are trying to show `value-label` for your autocomplete??

Comment: [{"id":"1","label":"Metroid: Other M"}] works

[{"id":"1","title":"Metroid: Other M"}] doesn't

The script is hardcoded to look for "label" it seems, doesn't seem like there's a way to change that. I can easily change my backend to output label instead of title it's just a bit annoying.

Answer (score 2):

From the [fine manual](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) (regarding the `source` option):

> When a String is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. [...] The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.

And for local data:

> The local data can be a simple Array of Strings, or it contains Objects for each item in the array, with either a label or value property or both. The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element after the user selected something from the menu.

So, your JSON return should either be a simple array of strings or an array of objects like this:

```
[
    { label: 'Shown to humans', value: 'Value for the text input' },
     ...
]
```