# I cannot get jQuery-UI's autocomplete to display returned items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I cannot get the returning data from the server to display on my form using jQuery-UI's autocomplete widget. (A narrow "return box" forms beneath the input element, but is not populated)

I'm running the latest versions of jQuery and jQuery-UI, and my returning data is validated JSON (http://jsonlint.com/).  The validator plugin (which can cause similar problems) is not part of my page.

Any help will be gratefully received.

Thanks/Bruce

My js is:

```
var ac_config = {
    source: "scripts/ajax_studentroll.asp?id=do_name",
    select: function(event, ui){
        $("#s_name2").val(ui.item.sname);
    },
    minLength:2
};
$("#s_name2").autocomplete(ac_config);
```

My html is:

```
<form action="scripts/ajax_studentroll.asp?id=getinfo" id="getStudentInfo" method="post">
    <p>
        <label class="label20" for="s_name">Enter the user's first name or surname,</label>
        <input id="s_name2" name="s_name2" value="" type="text" />&nbsp;
        <button class="fg-button_s ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="submit">Get!</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

The returning JSON is of the form:

```
[{"sname":"David Jones"},{"sname":"David McKay"},{"sname":"David Perry"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autocomplete` widget expects an array of values.

If you are going to have a custom data format (which you do) you need to override the `_renderItem` on the autocomplete instance as shown at http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data (click the "View Source" link on that page and notice how they get the instance form the input's `.data()`, and override `_renderItem`)

Comment: Thank you - this added to my recent discovery at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527704/stumped-cannot-get-results-to-show-with-jquery-ui-autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

From the [fine manual](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#overview):

> **Expected data format**
>
> The data from local data, a url or a callback can come in two variants:
>
> - An Array of Strings:
>     `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
> - An Array of Objects with label and value properties:
>     `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

So your JSON isn't coming back in the format that the widget expects, you probably just want to adjust the server to return a simple array of matching strings:

```
["David Jones","David McKay","David Perry"]
```

Comment: +1 for a better explanation of my first sentence. Either the data format must be adjusted, or the `_renderItem` method must be overridden as I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you - I wish I could tick more than one.  Kick myself - I read the manual, but scrolled right passed the section you quote to the examples!